# Why is the absolute value of a complex number a floating point number?

Tags: python, math, absolute-value

In python3:

```
>>> abs(-5) == 5
```

and

```
>>> abs(5) == 5
```

but

```
>> abs(5+0j) == 5.0
```

Comment: Because that's how it's mathematically defined: the norm of the real and imaginary components. Right?

Comment: This isn't really a Python question. See https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/absolute-value-complex-number

Comment: How about `5.0 == 5`?

Comment: If the argument of `abs` is integer the result must be integer, too; so it makes sense to have a special integer `abs` method. But the absolute value of a complex number need not be integer even if the real and the imaginary part are; so it makes no sense to have an "integer complex" `abs` method (even if there were an "integer complex" data type).

Answer (score 8):

The absolute value of a complex number a+bj, is defined as the distance between the origin (0,0) and the point (a,b) in the complex plane. In other words, it's sqrt(a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: Your statement is absolutely correct but does not answer the question. In this particular case, sqrt(5^2 + 0^2) = 5. Looks like an integer but the function returns a real unlike the abs() function that when an integer is input, it returns an integer. It is answered better below.

Comment: @DanSp. You just downvoted all the answers for not fitting your understanding of OP's question. While you are free to downvote if you think an answer is not correct, keep in mind that having diversified interpretation of the question may lead to better answers emerging.

Answer (score 3):

Because the absolute value of a complex number is the distance from origin to the number on the complex plane (where the two components of the complex number form the coordinates).

The imaginary `i` and real `r` components of a complex number can be seen as coordinates on a plane, and you can calculate the distance from the origin (`(0, 0)`) by using Pythagorean distance formula, `sqrt(i**2 + r**2)`.

The distance can be expressed as a floating point (real) number, there is no imaginary component.

It also can’t be an integer, because the Pythagorean distance is not always a convenient whole number (unlike the absolute value of an integer, which can only ever be another integer).

Comment: He is not asking why there is no imaginary component, he is asking why it returned a real instead of an integer. His example answer happens to be an integer. The abs() function returns an integer when an integer is input.

Comment: @DanSp: that’s far from clear.  Nowhere is it stated what they expected. The only thing we know for certain they didn’t expect a float. You are making assumptions here about what they didn’t understand.

Comment: You are correct, he is not expecting a float. But then gives examples that are deliberately integer and then asks about a complex number with integer coefficients. Nowhere is he asking what abs() means for a complex numbers. I think it is obvious what he is asking and I downvoted the answers which I honestly believed did not even address the question. I remove my downvotes because there is presumption in my action.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you know about the definition of the norm of a complex number, then your question becomes: why is `abs(5j)` returning `5.0` instead of `5` even though you provided an `int` as imaginary component?

The answer is *type consistency*. Since `abs` returns a `float` for complex numbers, there is no reason to make a special case and return an `int` if the output happens to be a round number.

Also, note that the same reasoning applies for the components of your imaginary numbers which are always stored as `float`.

```
z = 1 + 1j
z.real # 1.0
z.imag # 1.0
```

Comment: abs() does not return a float if an integer is input, it returns an integer. He is wondering why then when he inputs integer values in a complex variable that it returns a real. Well, there is no 'integer' complex type. (Would not be very useful would it.) Even though he typed integer coefficients, complex numbers are stored as two reals hence abs() of a complex number (with integer looking coefficients) always returns a real.

Comment: @DanSp. I believe you might have misread my answer as this is what I am explaining. Although, this misunderstanding led me to improve the part I think you might have found ambiguous, I did not mean to say that abs *always* return a float regardless of the input.

Answer (score 3):

I take it that the real question is “Why does Python's `abs` return integer values for integer arguments but floating point values for complex numbers with a plain integer value.”

Concerning the argument and result types of `abs` there are three main cases:

- argument is integer ⇒ result is integer; so it's safe to say that `abs(-5)` returns an integer (5).
- argument is real (floating point) ⇒ result is real; so `abs(5.1)` returns a floating point number (5.1).
- argument is complex ⇒ the result is a floating point number but the decision whether it has an exact integer value depends on the values of the real/imaginary parts of the argument.

This decision in the last case is far from trivial: *abs(5+0i)* has an integer value, so has *abs(3+4i)* (Pythagoras) but *abs(5+2i)* has not. In other words, it would not make sense to create an "integer complex" type and provide an `abs` implementation for it; the result would in most cases not be integer.

So it is quite sensible not to extend the integer/real distinction into the fields of complex numbers. (It would work for addition but the practical benefit would be close to zero.)

Comment: Finally, someone that tries to address the actual question. Well his arguments in the complex number are integers. More likely it is the fact that the square root must be taken. Even when supplied with integer values, the square root function is likely always returning a real value. `sqrt(5^2 + 0^2) = 5.0`

Comment: @Dan Sp. – I think you are right, the `sqrt` function plays a role here. Contrary to the real/integer `abs` function, for the `sqrt` function the integer-ness of the result is not determined by the *type* of the argument but only by its *value*. And typed programming languages like to overload their methods by the argument *types* only. There is no overloading by argument value, even less by result value. And, as I said, in order to consider the integer-ness of the real/imaginary parts of a number it would be necessary to introduce an "integer complex" type,  of little usefulness.

Comment: Yes, the [Gaussian integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer) ("integer complex type") are closed under addition and multiplication, but certainly not when square roots are involved. There's no reason to expect the complex modulus (absolute value) of a Gaussian integer to be an integer in general.

Comment: Indeed, the intrinsic 25 ** .5 = 5.0 even though 25 and the answer, 5, have whole values. Also the math.sqrt() function in the math module returns a real irrespective of the input.